# SQL order by after more than

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying SQL to sort results

```
id | name (table name: student)
-----
1 | jhon
2 | amin
3 | heli
4 | mir
5 | mrs
6 | amr
7 | jonnathan
8 | adhy
```

When i use this query

```
select id from studenth where id>='3' order by id DESC limit 2
```

The result that appears is

```
id | name (table name: student)
-----
8 | adhy
7 | jonnathan
```

Whereas I want to sort results after id = 3, I want the data as below

```
id | name (table name: student)
-----
4 | mir
3 | heli
```

Comment: remove single quotes in 'id' and order by asc limit 2

Comment: try my answer @Adhy Musaad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (select id from student where id >= 3 order by id limit 2) r order by r.id desc
```

Comment: What does the 'r' mean? Never seen in an sql query before.

Comment: It is actually 'as r', 'as' was omitted.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do some like:**

```
select * from student where id>=3 order by id LIMIT 2
```

If you want to take the records and sort it in descending order,then you can go for a subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT * 
  FROM student 
  WHERE id>=3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 2) X
ORDER BY X.id DESC
```

**Problem with your Query**

```
select * from student where id>='3' order by id DESC limit 2
```

The above query will take all the results with `id=3` or more and order it in the descending order and with `LIMIT 2` it will display only 2 records.

That's why it's displaying the last 2 records.

Comment: I want to take the data and sort it from the largest

Comment: @AdhyMusaad If you want to simply records with id=3 and 4 then use just order by id and limit 2.

Comment: @AdhyMusaad You want to take the 2 records i.e id=3 and id=4 and then sort it in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes in this `id>='3'`

```
select id from student where id>=3 order by id desc limit 2
```

**Update 1:**

Order by desc limit 2  problem here use subquery get the result then apply descending .

```
select * from (select id from student where id >= 3 order by id limit 2) new order by new.id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. You want everything less than or equal to 4 instead of everything after 3.

```
select id from student where id<='4' order by id DESC limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly , you want  the data in descending order from id +1 record. the query should be something like below:

```
select id from studenth where id<='4' order by id DESC limit 2;
```

Comment: That would give the expected result, in this case ; but you have to find a query that uses id '3' to keep OP's logic

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS** Use sub query it's easy to understand and fulfill your requirement:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM studenth 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM studenth 
             WHERE id >= 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 2) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT id,
       name
FROM tblTable
WHERE id >= 3
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT ( ( SELECT COUNT( * )
          FROM tblTable
          WHERE id >= 3 ) - 1 ), 2;
```

This statement works by sorting the records from `tblTable` based on the value of `id`.  It then uses `LIMIT` to select specific records from the sorted list.  If there are `20` eligibnle records this equates to `LIMIT 19, 2`, which will give us the 19th and 20th records.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.